# Can't get active directory group details by distinguished name

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, jndi

i am trying to get active directory group details by group dn as follows:

**1- connect to ldap:**

```
public static LdapContext connectToLdap(String host,
            String userDN, String userPassword,
            boolean ssl) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("connectToLdap");

        String hostPrefix = "ldap";
        String ldapPort = "389";
        if (ssl) {
            hostPrefix = "ldaps";
            ldapPort = "636";
        }
        String providerUrl = hostPrefix + "://" + host + ":" + ldapPort;
        //System.out.println("####### LDAP URL: " + providerUrl);
        LdapContext ldapContext;
        Hashtable<String, String> ldapEnv = new Hashtable<String, String>(11);
        ldapEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        ldapEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerUrl);
        ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userDN);
        ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, userPassword);
        ldapEnv.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout", 1000 * 10 + "");
        if (ssl) {
            ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
        }
        ldapEnv.put(Context.REFERRAL, "ignore");
        try {
            ldapContext = new InitialLdapContext(ldapEnv, null);           
            System.out.println("success connection to ldap");
            return ldapContext;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("failure connection to ldap");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**2- find group method:**

```
public static boolean isGroupExist(LdapContext ldapContext,
            String domain, String groupDN) {

        boolean exist = false;

        try {


            SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
            searchCtls.setTimeLimit(1000 * 10);

            String returnedAttrs[] = {"distinguishedName","cn"};
            searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAttrs);

            searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

            String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=group)(distinguishedName=" + groupDN + "))";

            NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = ldapContext.search(
                    domain, searchFilter, searchCtls);

            while (results.hasMoreElements()) {
                System.out.println("Success to retrieve active directory group with dn: " + groupDN);
                SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) results.next();
                Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
                String cn=attrs.get("cn").toString();
                System.out.println(cn);
                exist=true;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Fail to search in active directory groups");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return exist;
}
```

but when i am trying to use the isGroupExist method i am getting the following exception:

```
javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 12 - 0000217A: SvcErr: DSID-0314020F, problem 5010 (UNAVAIL_EXTENSION), data 0
```

please advise why i am getting this exception and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked fine after **removing** the following two lines:

```
String sortKey = LDAPAttributes.DISTINGUISHED_NAME;
            ldapContext.setRequestControls(new Control[]{new SortControl(
                        sortKey, Control.CRITICAL)});
```

Comment: Of course. "Unavailable critical extension" means that the request control or extended operation was marked "critical" but the server does not support it (or does not support it for that particular operation).

Answer (score 0):

You might get this to work using extensible match search, if you're using LDAP v3 and your search is part of the OU's DN attribute. Like http://www.novell.com/documentation/edir873/?page=/documentation/edir873/edir873/data/agazepd.html

Comment: Oops.. in less than a minute. :) I'm leaving this here in case someone stumbles across this and find this information useful.